Разработка в PHP Storm на базе ОС Alt Linux (не подключаются модули php)
Всем привет!
В рамках импортозамещения столкнулся с проблемой разработки на отечественной ОС.
Имеется лицензия на PHP Storm и ОС ALT Linux 10.2.
Вопрос следующий:
при разработке на Windows ставил php 7.4 и расширения к нему (например pgsql), настраивал xdebug в шторме и браузере.
Далее встоенным "веб-сервером" php отлаживал код (localhost:порт и так далее тоже прописывал в настройках). На Альте этот метод почему то не срабатывает: /?phpinfo будто не видит установленных расширений (в php -m они отображаются): прописывал в php.ini, ставил cgi... все равно при нажатии F5 в шторме у меня злополочная ошибка подключения... (креды бд корректные, сетевой доступ к бд есть).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение (может какой нибудь apache ставить или как? на винде и без него работает).

что такое : /?phpinfo? Что такое F5 в шторме? при чем здесь "креды к бд" если речь про отсутствующий модуль? что за "ошибка подключения"?

Http://localhost/?Phpinfo показывает конфигурацию php на проекте. Ошибка подключения функции pg_connect (undefined). После установки pgsql на винде, такой ошибки нет

Я понятия не имею, что такое у вас показывает Http://localhost/?Phpinfo, но если phpinfo() показывает наличие модуля pgsql, то функция pg_connect не может быть undefined. Так что вы или смотрите не то и не там, либо выполняете код не там, где смотрите. Если написать в скрипте <?php phpinfo(8); pg_connect();, то что он выведет?

В phpinfo не отображается наличие модуля pgsql. Его видно только в php -m

Теперь надо объяснить, при чем здесь phpstorm, и почему обращение к локальному серверу идет как Http://localhost/, без номера порта. Под линуксом нельзя задействовать 80 порт обычным пользователем и встроенный сервер обычно запускается под каким-нибудь портом типа 8000

обращение идет к localhost:8079

Чьё обращение? какое обращение? Откуда тогда взялось это ваше Http://localhost/?Phpinfo?  Почему нельзя было сразу нормально написать? Какой командой запускается встроенный веб-сервер? По каком удресу смотрите результат phpinfo?

Когда мы, находясь в phpstorm, нажимаем кнопку "F5" на клавиатуре запускается локальный веб сервер и мы имеем возможность отлаживать код используя браузер и xdebug (http://localhost:8089). Когда мы переходим по адресу http://localhost:8089/?phpinfo , мы видим конфигурацию php

ну значит phpstorm использует не тот РНР, который в консоли, а какой-то другой

В окружении Alt Linux 10.2, PHP 7.4, Xdebug наиболее работоспособным вариантом является использование Docker-контейнеров, например:

nginx;
php;
postgres.

